# How can I force a folder and the contents to be downloaded locally and not uploaded to the iCloud?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, folders, data-transfer, apple-store

I am trying to store a folder locally on my Macbook pro. I am running Catalina 10.14.4. Once I download the videos, they eventually all upload to the cloud and I have to redownload them. I am about to leave on a roadtrip and won't have internet access to redownload the file.

I have tried including a folder in the same location as the videos with *.nosync* in the name, but the files still upload.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations.
Thank you for your time,
Cameron

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried including a folder in the same location as the videos with .nosync in the name, but the files still upload.

But have you tried changing the name of the folder that *contains* the files to end with `.nosync`? iCloud Drive ignores the *contents* of folders named with `.nosync`, not the files that are in the same directory as such a folder. So, in your example, you'd change the name of the folder `Lecture Videos` to `Lecture Videos.nosync`.

Also—perhaps a simpler solution—you could simply move your `Lecture Videos` folder somewhere on your disk that isn't a subdirectory of `~/Documents` or `~/Desktop`, which are the two folders automatically synced to iCloud. For instance, you could put your `Lecture Videos` folder in `~/Pictures` or `~/Downloads`.

And, lastly, before you leave for your trip, you could go to System Preferences > Apple ID > iCloud and disable Optimize Mac Storage, which—if your laptop has enough free space—will (usually) prevent files from being automatically removed from your local disk once they're uploaded.